# Wordpress Rewrite rule to allow dynamic custom terms for an existing taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy

I am new to both wordpress and php. I have a custom taxonomy job_category for which I have a permalink set (jobs), under which there are categories such as engineering, accounts etc. So I can easily visit /jobs/engineering-jobs.

However, I would also like to accept dynamic terms such as jobs/it-jobs-in-usa.

For this I have read about rewrite rules and wrote the following:

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ){

$wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
    ['jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*-in{1}-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$' => 'index.php?

jobloc=$matches[1]'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );   
} );

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'jobloc';
    return $query_vars;
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    $jobloc = get_query_var( 'jobloc' );
    if ( $jobloc ) {
        include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'taxonomy.php';
        die;
    }
} );
```

However, this rule seems to be interjected by wordpress existing rules:

`'jobs/(.+?)/?$'`

And it does not find anything with that term (correctly so) so throws a 404. I have also tried to unset that rule but then it falls in another generic rule.

`[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$`

Is there a way for the above rule to kick in if it does not find anything instead of throwing 404. So:

jobs/it-job (taxonomy term found and it works as it does)
jobs/it-jobs-in-usa (not found but matches the above custom rule and takes to the required taxonomy.php page) where i can show results appropriately.

I am also using a theme so making changes in my child functions.php page.

Thanks for your help in this. Been at it for a while with different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was a plug in (permalink customizer) that was picking up a draft page with jobs/ url overwriting the query params thus Causing this issue.

Deleted the draft page and the rules are working now.